# NEHotspotNetwork.fetchCurrent is giving all Network not secure

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, security, networking

I'm trying to fetch current connected network (WiFi or hotspot or MobileNetwork). I'm using the below code snippet

```
    NEHotspotNetwork.fetchCurrent { hotspotNetwork in
            print("Network Information")
            print(hotspotNetwork?.ssid)
            print(hotspotNetwork?.isSecure ?? true)
            print(hotspotNetwork?.bssid)
            print(hotspotNetwork?.securityType)
            print(hotspotNetwork?.signalStrength)
```

I'm able to get the wi fi details. but one thing I noticed that it is giving every network as a **UnSecure** network whether it is password protected or not.How can we differentiate secure network and Unsecure network. Can anyone help me upstanding this. Thanks in advance.